# Archive of messages on Client-Server Java Swing app

Tags: java, swing, server, client

I rewrite some legacy Client-Server app in Java Swing. When I post message on Server - Client receive it, but I need a receiving the same message in Server archive too. In my case Server receive only last posted message, not all. Any ideas? Thank you

Server full code:

```
package chatapplication;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;
public class Server extends javax.swing.JFrame {

static ServerSocket ssckt;
static Socket sckt;
static DataInputStream dtinpt;
static DataOutputStream dtotpt;

public Server() {
    initComponents();
}



private void btnsendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    try {
        Date date = new Date();

        String msgout = "";
        String msgin = "";


        jTextAreaServ.setText("\n Archive : " + jTextField1.getText().trim() + "           " + date);

        msgout = jTextField1.getText().trim();
        //msgout = jTextAreaServ.getText().trim(); 
        dtotpt.writeUTF(msgout);

        jTextField1.setText("");

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}                                       

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

}                                           

public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Server().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your code does not have any components which shows how you are sending the message to the server. Please include relevant code.

Comment: Code was included

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
 private void btnsendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    try {
        Date date = new Date();

        String msgout = "";
        String msgin = "";
        msgout = jTextField1.getText().trim();
        jTextField1.setText("");

        dtotpt.writeUTF(msgout);


        jTextAreaServ.setText( jTextAreaServ.getText().trim()+ "\n Archive : "   + msgout + "           " + date);


    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```